# How to resize xen PV guest disks online?

Tags: cloud, virtualization, xen

How to resize xen PV guest disks online? Does anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are are looking to add disk space while the PV guest is in running state , you can use xm block-attach like this:-

```
xm block-attach <Domain Id> <Backend Device> <Frontend Device> <Mode>
```

Example :-

```
xm block-attach my_running_guest_id file://my_path_of file /dev/xvdc w
```

This backend device file can be created using a dd command.

Running `xm block-list $guest1_name | tail -1 | awk '{print $(1)}'`
should give you the info about the attached device if it is added successfully.

Please refer this [link](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Adding_Disk,_CDROM_and_DVD_Devices_to_a_Running_Xen_domainU_Guest_System).

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm not meaning add a new disk. What I want to do is re-sizing an already attached disk.